# Edit PostgreSQL database with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, sql

I have an ArcPy script that works locally with a .gdb database and create some features in this local DB. I would like to migrate my infrastructure on a server and do the same work but on a PostgreSQL db. I already created the database and its table with pgAdmin4 but I am having troubles understanding how to write on the database with ArcPy and I don`t find many resources online.

to initiate a connection I tried

```
arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(server='localhost',
                       instance='sde:sqlserver:localhost',
                       database='mydatabase',
                       user='postgres',
                       password='password')
```

but I receive this error

> RuntimeError: Object: Connection error Connection was attempted with
> an older version of SQL Server client communications software that is
> not supported.

Should I install ArcGIS Enterprise?

Comment: Cursors work the same way against any geodatabase, shapefile or layer so I think you should remove that question and focus on where you are currently stuck on connecting to your enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: Your usage is *very* wrong: First off, you can't connect to PostgreSQL using a Microsoft SQL Server connection string. Second, you should not ever connect to a generic SQL cursor with the administative user (`postgres`) Third, you should create a connection file with a less privileged login user, and use that. Many processes that work with a FGDB  workspace will just work with a PostgreSQL connection file, but some won't without enabling an enterprise geodatabase. This is a very broad topic; you need to bring very specific problems to GIS SE.

Comment: thank you Vince, I understand what you mean, to edit my workflow in the proper way I have created a new user in pgAdmin4 with less privileges. then I set the owner of my database to this user. this way I should be able to login with the newUser credentials. but still I am not able to access the DB with arcpy